# How to set min of selected range for a date slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, slider, date-range

I'm using [jQDateRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html) in my project to enable users to choose flight dates. 
Here is an example: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4YKN/). There are two types of bounds:

- Total bounds

  `bounds: {
  min: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
  max: new Date(2012, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)
  }`
- default selected range

  `defaultValues: {
  min: new Date(2012, 1, 10),
  max: new Date(2012, 4, 22)
  }`

Let's say I want to represent full year as total range(Jan - Dec). Users can select flight date(left label) and back date(right label) throughout the year. How can I set min for right slider lable no less than value in left label? Back flight date shouldn't be less than 1st date. Or in another words: how to disable all dates which is less than 1st selected date? According to documentation there is no standart solution to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    range: {min: new Date(2012, 0, 1)}, //use minimum range
    bounds: {
           min: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
           max: new Date(2012, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)
            },
    defaultValues: {
           min: new Date(2012, 1, 10),
           max: new Date(2012, 4, 22)
            }

      });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/Q4YKN/1/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. My problem is solved, but partially. Now right date can't be less than left one. Very simple solution. But also, what I forgot to say, that the 1st day also needs to be limited by today's date. By using this solution it's impossible to limit 1st date. But I find out disscution regarding this [here](https://github.com/ghusse/jQRangeSlider/issues/85). There are some proposed solutions how to ovveride js code to enable range limitations. So, by combining both solutions my issue has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry.. how possible can someone get the values obtained by selecting a slider. For instance, if someone moves the slider to 2012-10-20 and 2012-11-02, how would someone get the values